# OMNeT++: Uavsim Simulation can not run

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to run [Uavsim](https://github.com/ayjavaid/OMNET_OS3_UAVSim) (OMNeT++ based drone simulator) on Ubuntu 18.04 but getting some error when I trying to open it with "omnetpp" command.
It shows a message box and says that "An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/XxX/Desktop/uavsim/ide/configuration/1551888566822.log."

```
!SESSION 2019-03-05 01:09:31.019 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=10.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-03-05 01:09:33.250
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System Bundle could not be resolved: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the correct version of OMNeT++. Since the last commit on GitHub was four years ago, the code probably won't work with OMNeT++ 5.4.1. However, were you able to run "./configure" for OMNeT++ without any errors?

Comment: Yes i can, i also made "make" and compile all things. When I trying to open the simulation with "omnetpp" command, i get above error

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded java version to J2SE-1.5 and it works now